# How do I switch layouts in PyQt/Python? (Advanced)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

Update 1:
After making the following corrections:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    success = QtCore.pyqtSignal() # Might be QtCore.pyqtSignal
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Username = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)  
        self.Password = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.buttonLogin = QtGui.QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        loginLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        loginLayout.addRow("Username", self.Username) 
        loginLayout.addRow("Password", self.Password)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(loginLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.Username)
        layout.addWidget(self.Password)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
    def handleLogin(self):
        if (self.Username.text() == 'example' and
            self.Password.text() == 'example'):
            self.success.emit()
            # OR you know that the main window is the parent of this class
            # so you could call self.parent().P_3()
            # Signals are better though
        else:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Error', 'Incorrect Username/Password combination!')

class Page3(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page3, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Hello = QtGui.QLabel('Hello')
        layout.addWidget(self.Hello)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class page1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(page1, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.nextpage = QtGui.QPushButton('Page2')
        layout.addWidget(self.nextpage)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        Page1 = page1(self)
        Page1.nextpage.clicked.connect(self.P_2)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(Page1)
    def P_2(self):
        page2 = LoginWidget(self)

        # Connect your signal to a method. When success is emitted it will call P_3()
        page2.success.connect(self.P_3) # Note: P_3 does not have "()" with it

        self.central_widget.addWidget(page2)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(page2)
    def P_3(self):
        print("yay")
        page3 = Page3(self)
        # self.central_widget.addWidget(Page3) # you are calling the class (lowercase)
        # self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(Page3) # calling the class (lowercase)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(Page3)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(Page3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    User = ''
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()
```

I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hamzah\My Documents\Work\A-Level\USB Stuff\Pie Chart 2.py", line 66, in P_3
    self.central_widget.addWidget(Page3)
TypeError: QStackedWidget.addWidget(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType

Question:

The code below shows an example of switching layouts between page 1, login page (page 2) and page 3. However I cant seem to switch the layout from page 2 to page 3. I can switch the layout from page 1 to page 2 though?! By the way, when running the program (if your running it) the login details are 'example' and 'example' or view the code for the details:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        Page1 = page1(self)
        Page1.nextpage.clicked.connect(self.P_2)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(Page1)
    def P_2(self):
        page2 = LoginWidget(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(page2)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(page2)
    def P_3(self):
        print("Why won't the page open!!!???")
        page3 = Page3(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(Page3)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(Page3)

class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Username = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)  
        self.Password = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.buttonLogin = QtGui.QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        loginLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        loginLayout.addRow("Username", self.Username) 
        loginLayout.addRow("Password", self.Password)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(loginLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.Username)
        layout.addWidget(self.Password)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
    def handleLogin(self):
        if (self.Username.text() == 'example' and
            self.Password.text() == 'example'):
            MainWindow().P_3()
        else:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Error', 'Incorrect Username/Password combination!')

class page1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(page1, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.nextpage = QtGui.QPushButton('Page2')
        layout.addWidget(self.nextpage)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class Page3(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page3, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Hello = QtGui.QLabel('Hello')
        layout.addWidget(self.Hello)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    User = ''
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showFullScreen()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your LoginWidget. handleLogin is creating a new MainWinow and trying to call page 3.

You don't want to create a new main window, and you don't want an instance of a main window required for your login.

I would suggest using signals

```
class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    success = QtCore.Signal() # Might be QtCore.pyqtSignal

    ...
    def handleLogin(self):
        if (self.Username.text() == 'example' and
            self.Password.text() == 'example'):
            self.success.emit()
            # OR you know that the main window is the parent of this class
            # so you could call self.parent().P_3()
            # Signals are better though
        else:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Error', 'Incorrect Username/Password combination!')

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def P_2(self):
        page2 = LoginWidget(self)

        # Connect your signal to a method. When success is emitted it will call P_3()
        page2.success.connect(self.P_3) # Note: P_3 does not have "()" with it

        self.central_widget.addWidget(page2)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(page2)
```

If you need arguments where a signal is concerned use the lambda function.

```
page2.success.connect(lambda arg="": method(arg))
```

Also Note the error in P_3

```
def P_3(self):
    page3 = Page3(self)
    # self.central_widget.addWidget(Page3) # you are calling the class (lowercase)
    # self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(Page3) # calling the class (lowercase)

    self.central_widget.addWidget(page3)
    self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(page3)
```

Comment: It sort of works but when i run the code, i get this error:           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hamzah\My Documents\Work\A-Level\USB Stuff\Pie Chart 2.py", line 66, in P_3
    self.central_widget.addWidget(Page3)
TypeError: QStackedWidget.addWidget(QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'

Comment: I use PySide which is almost the same as Pyqt (Licensing and some syntax differs). It works on mine. The Signal/Slot functionality might be different for pyqt. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Comment: @HamzahAkhtar Did you make sure you changed addWidget and setCurrentWidget in P_3 to page3 (lowercase)? Before it was calling the class Page3.

Comment: Emitting a signal is the right approach. Ideally, each page should be able to function on its own without needing to know anything about the context in which its operating.

Comment: Yeah i changed it to lowercase

Comment: @Hamzah don't forget to accept answers that solved or helped solve problems.